# Is it possible to create a python script using instapy where we have listed few insta accounts and it just checks their latest post and likes it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instapy

Don't know how to approach. Any idea or suggestions regarding this are welcome.
Have seen few likes function that are already defined, but I don't want to like by tags as it would like posts of spam accounts also then using the same hashtag.
So I want it to like only genuine posts.

Comment: Your worried that your spam postings might look like spam postings?

Comment: no, this is just to increase account activity.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.